# C# Getting a specific position in a List

Tags: c#

Im seeking for a tiny help with a List I have
So, I have a List, which can change at any time, its quite long so I wont post it,
I want to get a specific position because I want to insert a new Line into it outside of its source. Here is a small thing that might explain it

Before

```
public class ListSourceView
{
    public List<Stuff> Blah =  new List<Stuff>("Hello", "Principal", "Johnson,", "How are you?");
}
```

So, we have a List called Blah with 4 things in it, now I would like to put a new String before Principal, ***but*** regardless if there are more strings in the list. (Aka Blah.Insert(2, "Mr") would not work) Best Case scenario would be something like Blah.Insert(Principal.positionInTheList - 1, "Mr") but am unsure what to use here.

Hope ya help a buddy out

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use:

```
int index = Blah.FindIndex(a => a.StartsWith("Principal"));
```

then you can insert a new item at/before/after the `index` by using

```
Blah.Insert(index, "newEntry"); //at index
Blah.Insert(index - 1, "newEntry"); //before index
Blah.Insert(index + 1, "newEntry"); //after index
```